# entity classes are not showing when trying to create new session beans for entity classes in netbeans 9.0

Tags: netbeans, ejb

i created java ee appliation that uses glassfish server 4.1.2 (i'm using java 8), it created just fine, then i created entity classes from database (i'm connecting to a database that has only one table called student) and it also went just fine, the problem appears when i got to the step that says i will create session bean for those entity classes, now while i'm doing this step i always stuck in the part of it :
[image]
as you can see it always says scanning in progress and stuck on that, i didn't any solution for it no matter how i tried.

i tried several things like restarting glassfish server, restarting netbeans, tried clean and build project option, none of them seemed to work, can someone please help me ??